# (Flutter) problem with aab (android apk bundle)

Tags: flutter

I cant publish my update aab in console play because version code of aab. I already changed the code, but not work. Console still read as version code 1. Anyone can solve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update below line in your pubspec.yaml file, increase the +1 every build and run flutter pub get after save

```
version: 1.0.0+1
```

eg.

first build 1.0.0+1

second 1.0.0+2

and goes like this